how to prevent Vuetify's v-date-picker `type` from changing date format
I have a datepicker and I'm trying to restrict the selections between 'month' and date but when I switch the v-date-picker's type from 'date' to 'month', the date format changes from 2024-01-01 to 2024-01
here is the datepicker
<v-date-picker
  v-model="from_date"
  :active-picker.sync="computeCalendar"
  :type="computeCalendar"
 />

and here is how I change the type and date
changePeriod({val = new Date}){
this.computeCalendar = this.period === 'Yearly' ? 'month' : 'date' 
  if (this.period == 'Yearly') {
   this.from_date = moment(val).startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  }
}

when I try watching from_date
watch: {
    from_date(val) {
      console.log("changed ", val)
    }
 }

I get this from the console
changed  2024-01-01
changed 2024-01

I'd like to restrict the selection of the date picker between month and date by setting the type prop dynamically and the date format to be consistent without being altered.
I'm using vuetify ^2.6.10 and nuxt ^2.15.8

2024-01-01 is not representative. If this were 2024-01-31 in "date" mode, what day would it be?

what do you mean its not representative. as stated the problem happens when I switch back to 'month' and formats the 2024-01-01 to 2024-01 i guess to just YYYY-MM instead i'd like it to stay YYYY-MM-DD. if i set the type to month from the start, the problem is not there so the switching kind of messes up with the format.

I mean if it was 2024-01-31 in "date", and you switch to "month", should it become 2024-01-01 or stay 2024-01-31?

yes. I am changing the from_date in the  changePeriod function to pick the first day of the year so it picks 2024-01-01

Finally found a hot fix using the watch from_date. so whenever the date picker changes to the format '2024-01' I'll add '-01' to the end of it.
watch: {
    from_date(val) {
      if (val && val.length === 7) {
        this.from_date = val + '-01'
      }
    }
  }


This is the way it needs to be done. The component is hardcoded to work this way, this couldn't be changed without extending it.
